# Eclipse 4 RCP, is it possible to exclude/include extensions conditionally

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, offline, rcp

I'm working on an Eclipse rcp application which is using a middle layer to request data. I want to run my application in offline mode i.e. if data service is not available I should be able to work on some dummy data. For this purpose I want to exclude/ include extensions (not extension points but extension point providers). Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the live and test versions of the extension point implementation in different plugins you can then choose which plugins to include in the product build - so you would have two product configurations, one for testing and one for production. When you are testing in Eclipse you can configure the plugins to include in the Run Configuration, so again you would have a test and production configuration.

It might also be possible to use a plugin fragment to contain just the part which varies. Use New / Project / Plug-in Development / Fragment Project to create.

Comment: Thanks greg-499, that would help me. I found out there are some direct  dependency as well which are not through extension point and extension  mechanism. What will be your suggestion there. Including/excluding plugins on run configuration will only help if I could have two plugins with same name(one for test and other for live), my point is there are many other common plugins which should work for both environments without changing their direct dependencies. I hope I'm making myself clear.

Comment: You might be able to use two fragment plugins to contain just the varying parts (edited answer to include this).

Comment: I tried to use fragment of my project but doesn't seem to work in eclipse ide 4.3.

Comment: I created a fragment project xyzOffline and specified xyz plugin as host. I expected during runtime xyzOffline modified classed will get loaded but instead xyz ones are loaded all the time. I found this bug too: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376486

Comment: greg-499 could you point me to a working example using fragments. Thanks

Comment: That bug is talking about Eclipse e4 application model fragment.e4xmi, not a fragment.xml plugin. It has been some time since I used a fragment to override code so I don't have any examples to hand. I remember using this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Steps_to_use_Fragments_to_patch_a_plug-in